# How can I find the name of the signatures folder?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

The folder where Outlook stores email signatures is `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures`.

However, the name can be different on non-English systems. How can I get the name of that folder reliably?

Answer (score 1):

The name is stored in this registry key:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General\Signatures
```

The version number (`16.0`) depends on the version of Office that is installed.